# Issues while displaying JSON data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having an issue while displaying json data in an html table. I believe it has to do with the fact that my json's formatted really strange (i can't change it)
Thanks in advance.

```
{"name":["instance-5","instance-6"],"id"["1178823664323071067","5394281241544297728"],"ip":["35.189.8.115","35.201.16.102"],"status":["RUNNING","RUNNING"]}

<script> 

$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/instance/list',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data){
    },
    success: function(data){
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append('<td>' + data.name + '<td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + data.id + '<td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + data.ip + '<td>');
        tr.append('<td>' + data.status + '<td>');


        $('#application-table').append(tr);           
    }
});
});

</script>

<table id="application-table" class="aui">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">Instance Name</th>
        <th width="20%">ID</th>
        <th width="20%">IP</th>
        <th width="5%">Status</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: is this the actual json response? have you copied it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is formatted such that each property is its own array, presumably meaning that `name[0]` is related to all the other `[0]` indexed items in the other arrays.

Therefore to achieve what you require you can loop over the response and put all the values within the properties at the same index within the new row, like this:

```js
var data = {
  "name": ["instance-5", "instance-6"],
  "id": ["1178823664323071067", "5394281241544297728"],
  "ip": ["35.189.8.115", "35.201.16.102"],
  "status": ["RUNNING", "RUNNING"]
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.name.length; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr>');
  tr.append('<td>' + data.name[i] + '<td>');
  tr.append('<td>' + data.id[i] + '<td>');
  tr.append('<td>' + data.ip[i] + '<td>');
  tr.append('<td>' + data.status[i] + '<td>');
  $('#application-table').append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="application-table"></table>
```

That said, I'd recommend finding a way to change your response structure to relate row data in each item of a single array, something like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "instance-5",
  "id": "1178823664323071067",
  "ip": "35.189.8.115",
  "status": "RUNNING"
}, {
  "name": "instance-6",
  "id": "1178823664323071067",
  "ip": "35.201.16.102",
  "status": "RUNNING"
}]

var html = data.map(function(row) {
  return `<tr><td>${row.name}</td><td>${row.id}</td><td>${row.ip}</td><td>${row.status}</td></tr>`;
});
$('#application-table').append(html.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="application-table"></table>
```

Comment: The op wrote, that they can't change the response

Comment: I know, which is why I offered it as alternative to help the OP and any future visitors as to how best structure response data for tabular display.

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly, I really appreciate it, Rory. Have a nice night.